# How to make multiple where->like() with Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I tried making a nest on a :

```
$where = new Where();
```

I also tried making multiple :

```
$where->like
```

Could someone please provide me an example of how I can make multiple like ?
I would like to search two different fields with the same value `%$value%`

Thank you and best regards

Comment: You should create an answer and mark that answer as the solution or remove the question, not edit an answer into the question (by definition, a question !== an answer).

Comment: Thank you for the info, I was wondering !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the `Where` object you can `NEST` (wrap in parenthesis) your options and specify an operator (in this case, `OR`):

```
$where = new Where();
$where->NEST
    ->like('field1', '%value%')
    ->OR
    ->like('field2', '%value%')
    ->UNNEST;
```

This will generate:

```
... WHERE (`field1` LIKE '%value%' OR `field2` LIKE '%value%')
```

Answer (score 0):

Found solution by using OR on the final select. The following example shows it :

```
$where = array();
$where[] = $rel->field1 . " LIKE '%". $value ."%' ";
$select->where($where, 'OR');
```

I'm not including the foreach but you get the idea, add your queries in where and use OR as predicates will generated for multiple entries.

Answer (score 0):

Extending above solution with more functional way :

```
$where = new Where();
$where->nest()
    ->like('field1', '%value%')
    ->OR
    ->like('field2', '%value%')
    ->unnest();
```